# higher-order potential interpretation in image segmentation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, mathematical-optimization, image-segmentation

I cannot find the mining of potential, higher order potential, low order potential and how higher order potential enhances image segmentation. is their any documentation to explain these concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the seminal work of:

Kohli, Pushmeet, and Philip HS Torr. [**Robust higher order potentials for enforcing label consistency.**](https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/ladickyl/robust_cvpr08.pdf) *International Journal of Computer Vision 82.3 (2009): 302-324*.

If you want to play around with som ecode, you can find a matlab wrapper [here](https://github.com/shaibagon/robustpn).